# Dynamically move mails into matching mailboxes with sieve fileinto regex

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, regex, sieve

I'm trying to create a sieve script, which files mails into mailboxes (or sub-directories of the inbox) matching a certain subject identifier.

For example if the subject includes `123` (three digits, 0-9), the server should check if a mailbox matching the same identifier exists, such as `Foobar 123` and if so, file the mail into that mailbox, otherwise have it stay in the inbox.

Checking the identifier in the subject header is no problem and I can assign the matched value to the variable `${1}`.

However, the `fileinto` command does not work with the `:regex` argument. As reported by `sieve-test`:

```
error: unknown tagged argument ':regex' for the fileinto command (reported only once at first occurrence).
```

Here's the sieve script I currently have:

```
require ["fileinto", "regex", "mailbox", "variables"];

if header :regex "Subject" "([1-9][0-9][0-9])" {
        fileinto :regex "INBOX\..*${1}.*";
}
```

Is there an approach I can take to first identify a matching inbox and assign that to the variable, or combine `fileinto` with `regex`?

**Edit**: I've also learned, that the `mailboxexists` test does not seem to work with `:regex` either.

`error: unknown tagged argument ':regex' for the mailboxexists test (reported only once at first occurrence).`

Answer (score 1):

Stick the match into a variable and use that:

```
require ["fileinto", "regex", "mailbox", "variables"];

if header :regex "Subject" "([1-9][0-9][0-9])" {
    set "mbox_candidate" "INBOX.${1}";
    if mailboxexists "${mbox_candidate}" {
        fileinto "${mbox_candidate}";
        stop;
    }
}
```

Maybe the whole mistake was to add `:regex` for `mailboxexists` and `fileinto`. I believe you could just sprinkle `${1}` into the arguments. But I would prefer using the extra variable anyway, to make the rule easier to read.